# Get Lightning Web Component (LWC) definition on a describe

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, ant, force

I need to describe a Salesforce Org that contains LWC, but the JSON obtained with the command:

```
sfdx force: mdapi: describemetadata -a 44.0 -u username
```

does not define me the LWC that should be shown as LightningComponentBundle. 
How could I get them?
I've tried both with ant and with Salesforce DX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LWC was introduced in latest release - Spring '19 and it's API number is 45.0 so if you describe your metadata using 44.0 MDAPI won't be able to see those components. You need to change "-a" parameter to "45.0"

```
sfdx force:mdapi:describemetadata -a 45.0 -u username
```

Comment: GREAT! Thank you! It works!